# Why my uploaded pages are not shown on the browsers?

Tags: asp.net

I create a web site via Visual Studio Web Developer. The exension of files are  .aspx. 
I had also uploaded those files to the hosting server by filezilla client. bt I can't show my pages on the net. Why?
If I write,  ../default.aspx, then I meet empty white page include NOTHING. 
When I see it on m local computer, there is no any prolem.
Please reply to me as fast as you can.
Best regards, Veli

Comment: Have you contacted your hosts tech support? They might be your best first line of support.

Comment: is the server capable to run asp.net ? Second, did you upload it to the correct directory ?

Comment: You asked if I uploaded it to the correct directory?- I think yes. I create an empty foder under publichtml then uploaded files into that folder –

Answer (score 0):

You will need to "publish" the site using the features in visual studio. This will compile all of your code into the appropriate dll which u will need to upload along with the aspx files

Comment: I published and debugged and looked it in Google Chrome. it was not any problem. Afer that I ploaded them all to the hsting server

Comment: Dear all. I want to ask anothe question: How can I export my .aspx files to html files?

Answer (score 0):

This depends on whether you app is a web site project, or a web application.  If it's a web application you'll have to build the site and publish it to your web host. If it's a web site project, you can simply copy the markup and the corresponding code-behinds up.

For more information regarding web deployment of asp.net projects you need to watch the "Web Deployment" section here.  It probably will answer many questions you might have regarding this.

[Building Applications with ASP.NET 4 WebForms](http://www.pluralsight-training.net/microsoft/courses/tableofcontents?courseName=aspdotnet-webforms4-intro)

Comment: You asked if I uploaded it to the correct directory?- I think yes. I create an empty foder under publichtml then uploaded files into that folder